Puppeteer: Page.navigate limit reached
My Json doctor name, profile page list
{
 {
    "name": "Herr Prof. Dr. med. Armin Quentmeyer",
    "link": "https://www.doctolib.de/orthopadie/ludwigshafen-am-rhein/dr-prof-armin-quentmeyer?pid=practice-238444"
  },
  {
    "name": "Herr Dr. med. Ralph Hower",
    "link": "https://www.doctolib.de/orthopadie/murnau-am-staffelsee/ralph-hower?pid=practice-228573"
  },
  {
    "name": "Orthopädische Praxis Ludwigsburg",
    "link": "https://www.doctolib.de/praxis/ludwigsburg/orthopaedische-praxis-ludwigsburg?pid=practice-570039"
  }
}

// website_adder.js
import puppeteer from "puppeteer-core";
import fs from 'fs';

async function addWebsites() {
    let browser;
    try {
        console.log("Starting function");
        const auth = '***';
        
        browser = await puppeteer.connect({
            browserWSEndpoint: `wss://${auth}@***`
        });

        // Read the JSON file with the list of doctors
        const data = fs.readFileSync('uniqueDoctorsData.json', 'utf-8');
        const doctorsData = JSON.parse(data);

        // Iterate through each doctor, visit their profile, and add the website to their data
        for (let doctor of doctorsData) {
            console.log(`Visiting profile of ${doctor.name} at ${doctor.link}`);

            try {
                // Introduce a short delay between navigations to avoid hitting the page limit
                await new Promise(resolve => setTimeout(resolve, 2000)); // Wait for 10 seconds
                console.log("Waited for 2000ms");

                // Use a new page for each doctor's profile
                const profilePage = await browser.newPage();
                await profilePage.goto(doctor.link, { waitUntil: 'networkidle2' });

                // Extract the doctor's website from their profile page
                const website = await profilePage.evaluate(() => {
                    const websiteElement = document.querySelector('a[rel="nofollow"][target="_blank"]');
                    return websiteElement ? websiteElement.href : null;
                });

                // Add the website to the doctor's data
                doctor.website = website;

                console.log(`Extracted website for ${doctor.name}: ${website}`);

                // Close the profile page to free up resources
                await profilePage.close();

                // Save the updated doctors data back to the JSON file immediately after processing each doctor
                fs.writeFileSync('uniqueDoctorsData.json', JSON.stringify(doctorsData, null, 2), 'utf-8');
                console.log(`Saved updated data for ${doctor.name} to JSON file`);

            } catch (error) {
                console.error(`Failed to navigate to ${doctor.link}`, error);
            }
        }

        console.log('All doctor profiles processed and data saved to updatedDoctorsData.json');

    } catch (e) {
        console.error('Failed to add websites', e);
    } finally {
        if (browser) {
            await browser.close();
        }
    }
}

// Export the function to be used in index.js
export { addWebsites };


I have this simple function to extract website from given website based on a json file where i gathered the names and the profilepages of the doctors. But no matter what I try I always get back a
Page.navigate limit reached

error. On Google and here I found this error nowhere else. Help much appreciated!!
I tried calling the pages one by one without a loop and a recursive loop. When I first visited the page before the loop and then inside the loop then i could visit 2 page in a row...
Edit minimal reproducible example:
// website_adder.js
import puppeteer from "puppeteer";
import fs from 'fs';

async function addWebsites() {
    let browser;
    try {
        console.log("Starting function");

        // Launch a new browser instance (no proxy connection)
        browser = await puppeteer.launch({
            headless: true, // Run in headless mode for efficiency
            args: ['--no-sandbox', '--disable-setuid-sandbox'] // Additional arguments to improve performance/stability
        });

        // Read the JSON file with the list of doctors
        const data = fs.readFileSync('uniqueDoctorsData.json', 'utf-8');
        const doctorsData = JSON.parse(data);

        // Iterate through each doctor, visit their profile, and add the website to their data
        for (let doctor of doctorsData) {
            // Skip doctors who already have a website to avoid unnecessary work
            if (doctor.website) {
                console.log(`Skipping ${doctor.name} as website is already added.`);
                continue;
            }

            console.log(`Visiting profile of ${doctor.name} at ${doctor.link}`);

            try {
                // Introduce a short delay between navigations to avoid hitting the page limit
                await new Promise(resolve => setTimeout(resolve, 2000)); // Wait for 2 seconds
                console.log("Waited for 2000ms");

                // Use a new page for each doctor's profile
                const profilePage = await browser.newPage();
                await profilePage.goto(doctor.link, { waitUntil: 'networkidle2' });

                // Extract the doctor's website from their profile page
                const website = await profilePage.evaluate(() => {
                    const websiteElement = document.querySelector('a[rel="nofollow"][target="_blank"]');
                    return websiteElement ? websiteElement.href : null;
                });

                // Add the website to the doctor's data
                doctor.website = website;

                console.log(`Extracted website for ${doctor.name}: ${website}`);

                // Close the profile page to free up resources
                await profilePage.close();

                // Save the updated doctors data back to the JSON file immediately after processing each doctor
                fs.writeFileSync('uniqueDoctorsData.json', JSON.stringify(doctorsData, null, 2), 'utf-8');
                console.log(`Saved updated data for ${doctor.name} to JSON file`);

            } catch (error) {
                console.error(`Failed to navigate to ${doctor.link}`, error);
            }
        }

        console.log('All doctor profiles processed and data saved to uniqueDoctorsData.json');

    } catch (e) {
        console.error('Failed to add websites', e);
    } finally {
        if (browser) {
            await browser.close();
        }

        // After processing the current batch, check again if there are any entries left without websites
        const updatedData = fs.readFileSync('uniqueDoctorsData.json', 'utf-8');
        const updatedDoctorsData = JSON.parse(updatedData);
        const remainingDoctors = updatedDoctorsData.filter(doctor => !doctor.website);

        if (remainingDoctors.length > 0) {
            console.log("Continuing to process remaining doctors without websites...");
            // Call the function again to process remaining entries
            await addWebsites();
        } else {
            console.log("All doctors have websites. Process completed.");
        }
    }
}

// Export the function to be used in index.js
export { addWebsites };


Thats wierd: This version with no Brigth Data connection, works just fine... I checked the log in Bright data but it is just fine

@ggorlen added the json and another version of the script. does it help?

It's a step forward, but the JSON isn't valid, so the code fails when run. I'm also missing index.js. If I make the JSON an array and call addWebsites() instead of exporting it, it runs for awhile scraping stuff, and I eventually killed the script, no error occurs. To be able to help, I need some code I can copy-paste into my editor, run without having to change anything, and see the error ideally instantly. How long do I need to run this script to see the error? What steps are necessary, exactly?

On Bright Data Docs it's stated that only a single navigation per session is allowed if you are programmatically navigating and not clicking around in the website.
Therefore if you want to scrape multiple sites by using the URLs and not by clicking around in the website, you need to recreate the session, one way is to close the browser and connect it again. e.g in your code you can close the browser and connect it again before navigating the doctor
 ...
 // Use a new page for each doctor's profile
 await browser.close();
 browser = await puppeteer.connect(browserConfig);
 console.log('Connected to browser');
 const profilePage = await browser.newPage();
 await profilePage.goto
 ...

